# Tuple to list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

Recently I'm doing a program and it requires me to convert a tuple to a list.

Tuples look like this: `[(1,[1,2,3,4]), (1,[2,3,4,5]), ...]`

And what I want is a list of: `[(1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5), ...]`

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Doe all the tuples have the *same* length? What is the `(1, ...)` thing doing here?

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog, `(1, 4, 2, 5)`, is syntactical sugar for `(1, (4, (2, 5)))`, just like `[1, 4, 2, 5]` is syntactical sugar for `[1|[4|[2|[5|[]]]]]` (note however that the list ends with an empty list `[]`, whereas for a tuple, it ends with a `(2, 5)`).

```
list_tuple([A, B], (A, B)).
list_tuple([A|T], (A, B)) :-
    list_tuple(T, B).
```

So then we can write a predicate to unpack the list out of the 2-tuple, and convert the list to a tuple:

```
conv((_, L), R) :-
    list_tuple(L, R).
```

and we can use [**`maplist/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) to perform the conversion over the entire list:

```
convlist(As, Bs) :-
    maplist(conv, As, Bs).
```

This then yields:

```
?- convlist([(1,[1,2,3,4]), (1,[2,3,4,5])], R).
R = [(1, 2, 3, 4),  (2, 3, 4, 5)] ;
false.
```

Tuples are however in Prolog not very common, so I do not see why you do not stick with the list itself.